# Apache returns 304, I want it to ignore anything from client and send the page

Tags: apache, cache, expires

I am using Apache HTTPD 2.2 on Windows. mod_expires is commented out. Most other stuff are not changed from the defaults. gzip is on.

I made some changes to my `.js` files. My client gets one 304 response for one of the `.js` files and never gets the rest. How can I force Apache to sort of flush everything and send all new files to the client?

The main html file includes these scripts in the head section of the main page:

```
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="js/trex.utils.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
    <script src="js/trex.core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
    <script src="js/trex.codes.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
    <script src="js/trex.emv.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
    <script src="js/trex.b24xtokens.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/trex.iso.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/trex.span2.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/trex.amex.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/trex.abi.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/trex.barclays.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/trex.bnet.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/trex.visa.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/trex.atm.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
    <script src="js/trex.apacs.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
    <script src="js/trex.pstm.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
    <script src="js/trex.stm.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
    <script src="js/trex.thales.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
    <script src="js/trex.fps-saf.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
    <script src="js/trex.fps-iso.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
    <script src="js/trex.app.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Apache access log has the following:

```
[07/Jul/2013:16:50:40 +0300] "GET /trex/index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 2033 "-" 
[07/Jul/2013:16:50:40 +0300] "GET /trex/js/trex.fps-iso.js HTTP/1.1" 304 
[08/Jul/2013:07:54:35 +0300] "GET /trex/index.html HTTP/1.1" 304 - "-" 
[08/Jul/2013:07:54:35 +0300] "GET /trex/js/trex.iso.js HTTP/1.1" 200 12417 
[08/Jul/2013:07:54:35 +0300] "GET /trex/js/trex.amex.js HTTP/1.1" 200 6683 
[08/Jul/2013:07:54:35 +0300] "GET /trex/js/trex.fps-saf.js HTTP/1.1" 200 2925
[08/Jul/2013:07:54:35 +0300] "GET /trex/js/trex.fps-iso.js HTTP/1.1" 304
```

Chrome request headers are as below:

This file is ok, latest:

```
Request URL:http://localhost/trex/js/trex.iso.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK (from cache)
```

THis file is ok, latest:

```
Request URL:http://localhost/trex/js/trex.amex.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK (from cache)
```

This one is also ok:

```
Request URL:http://localhost/trex/js/trex.fps-iso.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK (from cache)
```

The rest of the scrips all have 200 OK (from cache).

Comment: Can you post the header response the client gets? Of particular interest could be the ETag and Last-Modified values.

Comment: Are you saying that the client/browser does not even request the other js files after getting a 304 for just one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I enabled the `expires_module` and all seems to work now.